Update a value in a list of dictionaries
I have the following list of dictionaries:
"errorlist": [
    {
        "error": "Not found",
        "path": "/tmp/working/directory1/file1"
    },
    {
        "error": "Not found",
        "path": "/tmp/working/directory2/file1"
    },
    {
        "error": "Not found",
        "path": "/tmp/working/directory1/file2"
    },
    {
        "error": "Not found",
        "path": "/tmp/working/directory2/file2"
    }
]

I'd like to remove the "/tmp/working/" part of the path values, i.e. convert the absolute paths to relative ones.
I've been through similar questions while searching online but haven't found a solution. It should be rather simple but I can't wrap my head around it.
The expected result should be either the original list with updated values or a new list with the same structure.

Filter the basenames and create a list of dictionaries
  paths: "{{ errorlist | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') |
                         map('community.general.dict_kv', 'path') }}"

gives
  paths:
    - {path: file1}
    - {path: file1}
    - {path: file2}
    - {path: file2}

zip the lists and combine the items
  result: "{{ errorlist | zip(paths) | map('combine') }}"

gives
  result:
    - {error: Not found, path: file1}
    - {error: Not found, path: file1}
    - {error: Not found, path: file2}
    - {error: Not found, path: file2}

Fit the pipes to your needs.



Example of a complete playbook for testing

- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    errorlist:
      - {error: Not found, path: /tmp/working/directory1/file1}
      - {error: Not found, path: /tmp/working/directory2/file1}
      - {error: Not found, path: /tmp/working/directory1/file2}
      - {error: Not found, path: /tmp/working/directory2/file2}

    paths: "{{ errorlist | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') |
                           map('community.general.dict_kv', 'path') }}"
    result: "{{ errorlist | zip(paths) | map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: paths | to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: result | to_yaml


Fit the filters to your needs. For example, to remove any part of the string use the filter regex_replace

  paths: "{{ errorlist | map(attribute='path') |
                         map('regex_replace', '/tmp/working/(.*)', '\\1') |
                         map('community.general.dict_kv', 'path') }}"

gives
  paths:
    - {path: directory1/file1}
    - {path: directory2/file1}
    - {path: directory1/file2}
    - {path: directory2/file2}

This will result in
  result:
    - {error: Not found, path: directory1/file1}
    - {error: Not found, path: directory2/file1}
    - {error: Not found, path: directory1/file2}
    - {error: Not found, path: directory2/file2}



Q: "How can I achieve the same result without community.general.dict_kv?"
A: Use json_query. The below declaration gives the same result
  paths: "{{ errorlist | map(attribute='path') |
                         map('regex_replace', '/tmp/working/(.*)', '\\1') |
                         json_query('[].{path: @}') }}"

In Ansible 2.9 and lower try to add the filter list
  paths: "{{ errorlist | map(attribute='path') | list |
                         map('regex_replace', '/tmp/working/(.*)', '\\1') | list |
                         json_query('[].{path: @}') | list }}"



Debugging
Decompose the pipe
  path1: "{{ errorlist | map(attribute='path') }}"
  path2: "{{ errorlist | map(attribute='path') |
                         map('regex_replace', '/tmp/working/(.*)', '\\1') }}"
  path3: "{{ errorlist | map(attribute='path') |
                         map('regex_replace', '/tmp/working/(.*)', '\\1') |
                         json_query('[].{path: @}') }}"

and display the types of intermediary results
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ path1 | type_debug }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ path2 | type_debug }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ path3 | type_debug }}"



I also need the relative directory of each file, not only the basename.

Use regex_replace in the pipe. I added the example.

Testing in local environment worked but the real environment is Ansible 2.9.x and there's no community.general.dict_kv filter. How can I achieve the same result without it?

Use json_query. I added the example.

Had to add "| list" before json_query, otherwise paths variable was empty. But now I get "<generator object do_map at ....>" for result variable.

See Ansible: error: generator object is not iterable .... I added the example.

Ansible isn't a great tool for data manipulation. For what you want to do, the simplest solution is probably a custom filter written in Python. Drop the following into filter_plugins/filters.py (where the filter_plugins directory is in the same directory as your playbook):
def replaceInAttribute(data, attr, find, replace):
    for d in data:
        if attr in d:
            d[attr] = d[attr].replace(find, replace)

    return data


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {
            "replaceInAttribute": replaceInAttribute,
        }

And now you can write a playbook like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    errorlist: [
        {
            "error": "Not found",
            "path": "/tmp/working/directory1/file1"
        },
        {
            "error": "Not found",
            "path": "/tmp/working/directory2/file1"
        },
        {
            "error": "Not found",
            "path": "/tmp/working/directory1/file2"
        },
        {
            "error": "Not found",
            "path": "/tmp/working/directory2/file2"
        }
    ]
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ errorlist | replaceInAttribute('path', '/tmp/working/', '') }}"

And get this output:
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "error": "Not found",
            "path": "directory1/file1"
        },
        {
            "error": "Not found",
            "path": "directory2/file1"
        },
        {
            "error": "Not found",
            "path": "directory1/file2"
        },
        {
            "error": "Not found",
            "path": "directory2/file2"
        }
    ]
}

The filter presented here is slightly more complex than it needs to be, since it supports find/replace on arbitrary attributes.

I agree Ansible isn't a great tool for data manipulation but I'd prefer not to use Python. Thanks anyway.

@Jedi6, but Ansibe itself and almost every module, filter, etc. is written in Python. So you are going to use Python anyway. Even if you find the the cost of maintaining and operating an own Custom Filter high, it could be cheaper than maintaining and operating an Ansible playbook with a lot of out-of-box filters for complex data manipulation.
